# How can I make this navbar?

Tags: html, css

I found this ultra clean looking navbar on Instagram. But I don't exactly know how to make this one. Could someone help me please.

[Here is the image of it, I want to make the 4th one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UxvPk.png)

Comment: It's not a page. It's an image from Instagram

Comment: That's what I said. I'm asking how do I make that 4th navbar in the image it shows

Comment: You just responded your own comment...

Comment: Sorry but do you know how to make that

Comment: Stack Overflow is not for getting people to write code for you, if you are stuck than you ask a question, please add more detail. Look here;https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask here https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask .

Comment: Ok Sorry I did not know

Answer (score 1):

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

html,body{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #2d3132, #000) center/cover no-repeat;
  font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
}

ion-icon{
  margin-left:5px;
}

.nav{
  position:absolute;
  left:0; right:0; top:0; bottom:0;/* Purposes equal */
  margin:30px auto;
  width:90%;
  height:70px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(25deg, #d0c1cf 70%, #fffefc);
  display:inline-flex;
  font-size:16px;
}
.brand{
      
}
.item{
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-flex;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  color:rgba(0,0,0,.7);
  font-weight:bold;
  margin-left:20px;
  transition:500ms linear;
}

.get__start{
  position:absolute;
  right:30px;
  top:15px;
  padding:10px 15px 10px 15px;
  color:white;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #8600fa, #b600ec);
  border:none;
  border-radius:20px;
  font-size:16px;
  text-align:center;
}


.item:hover{
  color: #8600fa;
}

.get__start:hover{
  color:black;
}

[name="remove-outline"]{
  transform:rotateZ(90deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Cool nav</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="nav">
      <div class="item brand">
        <ion-icon name="logo-stackoverflow"></ion-icon> Ofin
      </div>
      <div class="item divider">
        <ion-icon name="remove-outline"></ion-icon>
      </div>
      <div class="item features">
          <ion-icon name="cube-outline"></ion-icon>
          &nbsp;
          Features
      </div>
      <div class="item plans">
          <ion-icon name="pricetag-outline"></ion-icon>
          &nbsp;
          Plans
      </div>
      <div class="item learn">
          <ion-icon name="book-outline"></ion-icon>
          &nbsp;
          Learn
      </div>
      <div class="item support">
          <ion-icon name="heart-outline"></ion-icon> 
          &nbsp;
          Support
      </div>
      <button class="item get__start">
          Get Started
      </button>
</div>

<!-- I connect  Ionicons framework, Reason: important icons-->
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```